# IOCelot Builder does not contain definition for AddAdministration

Tags: c#, api-gateway, asp.net-apicontroller, asp.net-core-6.0, ocelot

I'm using .Net core 6 and i get an error on the AddAdministration("/administration","secret") when trying to supports changing configuration during runtime on my API Gateway,is there an alternative i can use or missing an assemby reference?please see error attached.thanks

```
builder.Services.AddOcelot().AddAdministration("/administration","secret");
```

[image: error]

Comment: There is no method called .AddAdministration that is accepting two string parameters in class that is being returned by .AddOcelot(). That function indeed is declarated but in other object, try this code: `builder.Services.AddOcelot().AddPolly().AddAdministration("/administration","secret");`

Comment: @BartoszOlchowik forgot to mention i tried that also but still does not work..

Comment: same error message "IOCelot Builder does not contain definition for AddPolly"

Comment: make sure that you are using required namespaces, check if you have:
`using Ocelot.DependencyInjection;
using Ocelot.Middleware; `
Looks like you are not referencing them, and thats where those methods should be.

Answer (score 0):

i Was just missing the ocelot.Administration nuget package